I have multiple room type and each room type has multiple row for pricing
I have multiple room type and each room type has multiple row for pricing but while i perform calculation it calculate for each room type form but If i add new pax slab row for that room type then it unable to calculate it.
is there any possibilities to perform calculation for each row according to roomtype each row
@foreach ($all_room_types as $room_type)
                                                <div class="heading_room_name">Cost Per Person for {{ $room_type->room_type_name }} room</div>
                                                
                                                <table class='table table-bordered table-room-{{ $room_type->id }}'>
                                                    <p class="bg-dark m-0 p-1 text-white">Add Direct Cost</p>
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <b>Min. Pax<span style="color: red;">*</span></b>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <b>Max. Pax<span style="color: red;">*</span></b>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <b>Cost<span style="color: red;">*</span></b>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <b>Total Cost</b>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td width='25'>
                                                                <div class='mx-5'>
                                                                    <i class='fa fa-plus btn btn-sm btn-success add-pax-slab-row' data-room-type-id='{{ $room_type->id }}' style='cursor: pointer;'></i>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </td>   
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      
                                                        <div class="pax-slab-box">
                                                            <tr class='pax-slab-row-{{ $room_type->id }}'> 
                                                                <td>
                                                                    {!!  Form::select('min_pax[]', $min_pax, null, ['class' => 'form-control min_pax','placeholder' => 'Select min pax']) !!}
                                                                    {!! $errors->first('min_pax','<span class="help-block text-danger">:message</span>') !!}                             
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    {!!  Form::select('max_pax[]', $max_pax, null, ['class' => 'form-control max_pax','placeholder' => 'Select max pax']) !!}
                                                                    {!! $errors->first('max_pax','<span class="help-block text-danger">:message</span>') !!}                             
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    {!! Form::text('cost', null, ['class' => 'form-control cost-'.$room_type->id, 'placeholder' => 'Enter Cost']) !!}
                                                                    {!! $errors->first('cost','<span class="help-block text-danger">:message</span>') !!}                             
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    {!! Form::text('total_cost', null, ['class' => 'form-control total-cost-'.$room_type->id,'placeholder' => 'Total Cost', 'disabled' => 'true']) !!}
                                                                    {!! $errors->first('total_cost','<span class="help-block text-danger">:message</span>') !!}                             
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td width='25'>
                                                                    <div class='mx-5'>
                                                                        <i class='fa fa-trash btn btn-sm btn-danger remove-pax-slab-row' data-room-type-id='{{ $room_type->id }}' style='cursor: pointer;'></i>    
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </div>
                                                      
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>  

                                               
                                                
                                            @endforeach

@foreach ($all_room_types as $room_type)
    $('.cost-{{ $room_type->id }}').keyup(function() {
        
       
        var cost           = parseFloat($('.cost-{{ $room_type->id }}').val());
        var profit         = parseFloat($('.profit').val());
        var tax_percentage = parseFloat($('.tax-percentage').val());
        
        checkNum('.cost-{{ $room_type->id }}'); 
        total_cost = calculate_total_cost(cost, profit, tax_percentage);
        $('.total-cost-{{ $room_type->id }}').val(total_cost);
      
    }); 
@endforeach

